# jquery function not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I wrote this line of code to be executed upon a button `spin2` click

```
$("#spin2").countdown().show();
$(".wheel").css({"-webkit-transform": "rotate(180deg)"
```

The code for countdown is not seeming to execute. It looks like this:

```
time = 3;
$.fn.countdown = function() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        time--;
        document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = "" + time + " seconds"
        if (time == 0) {
            // stop timer
            clearInterval(interval);
            // click
            document.getElementById('stop2').click();            
        }
    }, 1000)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I assume it's something to do with my syntax

EDIT: upon completion the goal is for the code activated by pushing button `stop2` to execute. The problem is, there's no execution.
Code for the buttons:

```
<button id="spin2">Spin</button>
<button id="stop2" style="display: none;">Stop</button>
<button id="spin3" style="display: none;">Spin</button>
```

Another line of code which uses the function written, it's where the stop2 button appears:
`$("#spin2").click(function(){$("#spin2, .miss").hide();$("#stop2").show();`

Comment: Why do you call `.show()`?

Comment: @guest271314 to show a little popup which displays a message. Why do you ask?

Comment: _"So I wrote this line of code to be executed upon a button spin2"_ Is `#spin2` element `css` initially set to `display:none`? What issue are you having?

Comment: Did you call your function inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Your `countdown` function doesn't establish a click handler anywhere. It doesn't use `this` anywhere, what does it mean to apply it to a DOM element with `$("#spin2").countdown()`?

Comment: @guest271314 the code is not initially set to display:none. I set it to display:none and the object disappeared. I'll put in the code for the buttons.

Comment: @AlexanderWilkening How can user click element if `display` is set to `none`? What is expected result of `click` event being dispatched to `#stop2` element? Are you trying to display `#stop2` at completion of `.countdown()` called on `#spin2`?

Comment: @Barmar I followed Sinisake's solution and still am not seeing the results I'd like.

Comment: @AlexanderWilkening How are you making the function run when you click on the button?

Comment: I just added some more code which contains the segment of code which makes the button "stop2" visible.